# Unable to import play.db in Play project

Tags: java, scala, playframework

```
The import play.db cannot be resolved
```

How does one resolve this? I have already modified my `built.sbt`:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

And `application.conf`:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

And `plugin.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.1")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the version of the ebean plugin you are using, the packages have changed.  So now instead of (play 2.0-2.3):

```
import play.db.ebean.*
```

or (play 2.4-2.5, sbt-play-ebean 3.0.0):

```
import com.avaje.ebean.*
```

you would use (play 2.6, sbt-play-ebean 4.0.x):

```
import io.ebean.*
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean